# Histogram of 'components' in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I'm just starting with Neo4j, but there's something I'm wondering if it's possible using with Neo4j. If I have a multi-partite network with for example People, Phone Numbers, Flight Bookings (very rough example, so might not work perfectly)

In this network say People can have multiple phone numbers, Multiple people can be on a flight booking, multiple numbers can be on a flight booking.

If I created a network with this, I would have a lot of disconnected components. The majority of components would be:

- 1 person has 1 phone number and is on 1 booking.

There will be a few cases of:

- 2 people have 2 phone numbers and are on 1 booking.

Then as we continue, there will be more rare but complex components.

- 10 people have 30 phone numbers and are 5 booking.

Would it be possible to run a query to traverse the whole network and get a histogram of all these various component shapes:

- 1 person has 1 phone number and is on 1 booking. - 10,000 cases
- 2 people have 2 phone numbers and are on 1 booking. - 5,000 cases
- 10 people have 30 phone numbers and are 5 booking. - 2 cases

Can you do this sort of thing with Neo4j?

I hope this is clear, let me know if not! Thanks

edit: as per  Mohamed E. ManSour's suggestion, I've created a sample that might clear it up http://console.neo4j.org/?id=u8gzhu

Comment: Would try creating sample of your graph db using http://console.neo4j.org/ and let us see it, and I think you can easily query for you criteria using cypher..

Comment: Good idea, I didn't know about that demo page - as I say, very new to this! I tried to put one together on http://console.neo4j.org/?id=u8gzhu as you can see there are 4 separate components. Two of those are of the same format i.e. a person who has a phone number and is on a booking.

Comment: So, you simply have to create an index to use in queries..
And now, what is your query should looks like, or what is criteria you are looking for ??

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure how to phrase the question, but now I'm looking for a count of each component 'type'. Ultimately I'm looking for something like this http://i.imgur.com/RCrMKYH.png.

Comment: You're looking for a count of specific types of situations? 

Ex. 1 case of '1 person, 1 phone number, 1 booking', 3 case of `2 person, 2 phone number, 1 booking', etc. 

Would it be best to say that you want to try to find all subgraphs that have the same number of people, numbers and bookings?

Comment: Ok, the example I've given, that does make sense as probably the best way to go. However, if the connections get more complicated, for example 'A person can have a phone number' and 'A phone number can be on a booking'. Then counts alone wouldn't describe the situations. `2 person, 2 phone number, 1 booking' could have one person with two phone numbers and one with none, both people with one, one person with one and one booking with one and so on.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think this may be what you're looking for? It may be specific to your case, but this method of grouping things by counts seems like it would work for any single-level component.

http://console.neo4j.org/r/9w30x5

```
START p=node:node_auto_index('name:("Person_A","Person_B","Person_C","Person_D","Person_E")') 
MATCH num<-[:HAS]-p-[:IS_ON]-booking 
WITH p, count(distinct booking) AS bookings, count(distinct num) AS nums 
RETURN count(1), bookings, nums
```